# Assets/Scripts/GridManager.cs(24,16): error CS0118: `GridManager.Tile.TileControl' is a `field' but a `type' was expected

Tags: tile

Hi I'm creating a match of 3 game and I use this as my code, I got this from a [tutorial in the internet](http://videogamedesign24.com/how-to-create-a-match-3-game-in-unity-tutorial/), and copied and pasted it in visual studio 2013 but the code does not work. It says `GridManager.Tile.TileControl' is a 'field' but a 'type' was expected`
Can you help me with this code?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GridManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // A simple class to handle the coordinates.
    public class XY 
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public XY (int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

    // The tile class. Keeps track of the tile type, the GameObject, and its controller.
    public class Tile
    {
        public int TileType;
        public GameObject GO;
        public TileControl TileControl;

        public Tile ()
        {            
            TileType = -1;            
        }

        public Tile (int tileType, GameObject go, TileControl tileControl)
        {
            TileType = tileType;
            GO = go;
            TileControl = tileControl;
        }
    }

    public GameObject[] TilePrefabs;

    public int GridWidth;
    public int GridHeight;
    public Tile[,] Grid;

    private int movingTiles;

    void Awake()
    {
        CreateGrid();
    }

    void CreateGrid()
    {
        Grid = new Tile[GridWidth, GridHeight];        

        for (int x = 0; x < GridWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < GridHeight; y++)
            {
                int randomTileType = Random.Range(0, TilePrefabs.Length);
                GameObject go = Instantiate(TilePrefabs[randomTileType], new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                TileControl tileControl = go.GetComponent();                
                Grid[x, y] = new Tile(randomTileType, go, tileControl);
                tileControl.GridManager = this;
                tileControl.MyXY = new XY(x, y);
                go.name = x + "/" + y;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you post the link to the tutorial you are using?

Comment: http://videogamedesign24.com/how-to-create-a-match-3-game-in-unity-tutorial/ Here sir.

Comment: did you find the solution? I was following the same tutorial and had the same problem